# Is “this pie hot” in “do you want this pie hot?” a non-finite clause?

Tags: clauses, noun-phrases

> Do you want this pie hot? (from the Cambridge Dictionary)

Is “this pie hot” in “do you want this pie hot?” a non-finite clause or just a noun phrase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"This pie hot" is not a noun phrase. As a noun phrase it would be "this hot pie", because the adjective would have to come before the noun. This would change the meaning: in "Do you want this hot pie" the adjective "hot" is helping to specify which pie, but in "Do you want this pie hot" and similar sentences it is specifying a potential/future/required state of the pie.

This is a non-finite clause. It means the same as "this pie to be hot", so you could see it as an elision of "to be", though you can't elide "to be" in all sentences.

(This is different from "He saw the pie, hot, sitting on the table", where the commas are required and "hot" is providing extra information about the pie.)